NTUSER.DAT locked by System
I have a Windows 2022 as RDS server. Now I need to migrate users to another server. Can't migrate just one user even he singed out. The action can't be completed because the file is open in System for NTUSER.DAT file. Can't understand what's wrong.

In addition to Greg's answer, you could try to reboot the server to close all handle, if the handle come back after, then it's more probably an antivirus or such software that reopen the handle to the profiles's file.

There is an open handle to a resource in the user profile. You can view the resource use Sysinternals handle.exe. Resolving this typically requires restarting the server if the offending process is system.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

In my experience, there is no need to migrate this file, as it will always be blocked by the system. Migrating the files of the user makes almost 99% of them happy. Otherwise, you can use Roaming Profiles where you never need to worry about it.

A restart was needed. @djdomi, without NTUSER.DAT user can't use his own profile.

the specific settings, true. for the file nope
